# php fail to compare two exactly same string

Tags: php, string

I've following piece of code

```
$path = $resource['path'];
if (strpos($path, base_url()) == 0) {
    $path = FCPATH. substr($path, strlen(base_url()));
}
echo '<pre>';
$x = '/home/gofrendi/public_html/No-CMS/themes/ubuntu/assets/default/script.js';
var_dump($path);
var_dump($x==$path);
var_dump('/home/gofrendi/public_html/No-CMS/themes/ubuntu/assets/default/script.js' == $path);
echo '</pre>';
```

I'm sure that $path consists of `/home/gofrendi/public_html/No-CMS/themes/ubuntu/assets/default/script.js`

And this is what I get:

```
string(82) "/home/gofrendi/public_html/No-CMS/themes/ubuntu/assets/default/script.js"
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Seems that the comparison simply failed. What's wrong here? PHP bug or my mistake?

**EDIT:**
I also gladly show you the result of this code:

```
echo '<pre>';
$x = '/home/gofrendi/public_html/No-CMS/themes/ubuntu/assets/default/script.js';
var_dump($path);
var_dump($x);
var_dump($x==$x);
var_dump($x==$path);
var_dump('/home/gofrendi/public_html/No-CMS/themes/ubuntu/assets/default/script.js' == $path);
echo '</pre>';
```

The result is:

```
string(82) "/home/gofrendi/public_html/No-CMS/themes/ubuntu/assets/default/script.js"
string(72) "/home/gofrendi/public_html/No-CMS/themes/ubuntu/assets/default/script.js"
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

**EDIT AGAIN:**
Resolved, I do some str_replace for templating system that change `{{ used_theme }}` into currently used theme. The used theme is 'ubuntu' which has 6 character length, while {{ used_theme }} has 10 character length.
The str_replace performed after the code executed. This also change the var_dump result, which make such an unexpected behavior.
Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: Show us `var_dump($x);`.

Comment: It should be of length `72` but as we can see your var_dump($path) has `82` which is incorrect. Try `trim($path)` & check again.

Comment: Try `var_dump(htmlentities($path));`

Comment: No there is no spaces. I'll try Rikesh's suggestion

Comment: Look at page source. Not page itself.

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump(base_url())`?

Comment: That's probably some kind of characters encoding issue

Comment: +1 for encoding, try using `strtolower`, `trim` and `utf8_encode` for example :).

Comment: Are you defining `FCPATH` as a constant?

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ: Yes, FCPATH is a constant, defined by CodeIgniter, is it related to this?

Comment: What's the result of `var_dump(htmlentities($path))`?

Comment: @Barmar: this one: string(82) "/home/gofrendi/public_html/No-CMS/themes/ubuntu/assets/default/script.js", I wonder how could that mysterious 10 character added

Comment: let's try `var_dump(explode('/', $path))` to narrow down the search.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, This is the problem `string(16) "ubuntu"` I'll try to inspect it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can see there is some difference between the two `strings` one of them is of `length "82"` and the `other is of "72"`  there could be some invisible (non-printing) characters in the string

Answer (score 0):

There is some difference with your $path as it shows string(82) chars and $x has string(72) you must be some html chars isssue. Try trimming it and then compare.

Comment: var_dump would show whitespace. I think it's either non-printing characters or HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Characters encoding issue probably, if you have the mbstring extension enabled, try this and convert the encodings accordingly

```
echo mb_detect_encoding($x);
echo mb_detect_encoding($path);
```